# How do I update a row of data in mysql using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm attempting to create a form where the user can update their profile details but it just doesn't seem to work.

I'm quite the beginner in server side programming so I'm piecing together code from different tutorials viz. from http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/php-login-and-registration-script-with.html

The *class.user.php* file, which originally only had the code for login, and signup. I copied the signup function and changed some stuff to update instead:

```
public function update($id,$uname,$umob,$uaddr,$uacc,$upass) {
    try {
        $upass = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
            "UPDATE users
                SET
                    id       = :id, 
                    name     = :uname, 
                    mobile   = :umob,
                    address  = :uaddr,
                    accNo    = :uacc, 
                    password = :upass
              WHERE id = :id"
        );

        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
        $stmt->bindParam(":upass", $upass);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uacc", $uacc);                                         
        $stmt->bindParam(":uname", $uname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uaddr", $uaddr); 
        $stmt->bindParam(":umob", $umob);

        $stmt->execute();   

        return $stmt;   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }               
}
```

and in *view_account.php*: (edit 3, whole file including code corrections by @e_i_pi):

```
<?php
ini_set("error_log", "/path/to/error.log");
    require_once("session.php");

    require_once("class.user.php");

    $auth_user = new USER();

    $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE consumer-no=:cno");

    $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!$session->is_loggedin()){
        // session no set redirects to login page
        $session->redirect('index.php');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] === 'save') {
        $uname = strip_tags($_POST['full-name']);
        $umob = strip_tags($_POST['mobile']);
        $uaddr = strip_tags($_POST['addr']);
        $uacc = strip_tags($_POST['bank-acc']);
        $id = strip_tags($_POST['id']);
        $upass = strip_tags($_POST['password']);


        if($uname=="") {
            $signuperror[] = "Please Enter Your Full Name!";    
        }
        else if($umob=="")  {
            $signuperror[] = "Please Enter Your Mobile No.!";   
        }
        else if($uaddr=="") {
            $signuperror[] = 'Please Enter Your Address!';
        }
        else if($upass=="") {
            $signuperror[] = "Please Enter a Password!";
        }
        else if(strlen($upass) < 6) {
            $signuperror[] = "Password must be atleast 6 characters";   
        }
        else {
            try {
// I commented out these for some weird reason I can't even rememebr
//                $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=:id");
//                $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
//                $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $auth_user->update($id,$uname,$umob,$uaddr,$uacc,$upass);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }   
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gas Booking</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>gas booking</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="booking.php">booking</a></li>
                <li><a href="payment.php">payment</a></li>
                <li><a href="ticket.php">ticket</a></li>
                <li><a href="view_account.php">view account</a></li>
                <li><a href="user-bank.php">bank</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php?logout=true">logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Edit Your Profile Details</h2>

        <form method="post" action="view_account.php">
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">
            <label for="full-name" class="input-info">
                <div class="label">full name</div>
                <input type="text" id="full-name" name="full-name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>">
            </label>
            <label for="mobile" class="input-info">
                <div class="label">mobile number</div>
                <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['mob']; ?>">
            </label>
            <label for="addr" class="input-info">
                <div class="label">address</div>
                <input id="addr" name="addr" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['addr']; ?>">
            </label>
            <label for="bank-acc" class="input-info">
                <div class="label">bank account number</div>
                <input type="text" id="bank-acc" name="bank-acc" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['accNo']; ?>">
            </label>
            <hr>
            <label for="password" class="input-info">
                <div class="label">password</div>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            </label>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
                Save Changes
            </button>
        </form>     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my table is as follows:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `consumerNo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `accNo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `balance` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `joining_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I'm sure I've done something stupid. I'd really appreciate pointing me in the right direction, I sat with it till 5:00am and am feeling frustrated with myself.

The connection with the db is working, classes are properly included. Let me know if you need more information. Thank you!

The project can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9v69m18l82n1t46/gas.zip?dl=0. Warning the code's kind of a mess.

Comment: How are you defining the user `$id`? Is it in `$_SESSION`, or is it in a hidden field in the form? Can you show your form html

Comment: @Darren Yep, in a hidden field. I've added the form's html.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" isn't very informative.  An error message may be helpful.  Or telling us which parts are successful (e.g. echoing variables shows the correct stuff).

Comment: Well, allowing the user to alter the ID probably will allow anyone to set anyone else's data, including the password - but that is only AFTER you made your update script work. Additionally, why `strip_tags`? Especially for the password this is a bad thing because it might change the password by removing special chars and shortening it.

Comment: @mickmackusa not getting any helpful errors, none at all to be precise.

Comment: @Sven I'm following the tutorial I've linked in my post. Currently worried about getting the update part working and inspecting the rest later on.

Comment: Be careful about the binding order. You should bind in the order that the the placeholders appear in the *query*.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge I think that fixed the problem?!!!! Thank you!

Comment: I mis-spelled `$stmt->bindParam` for the last one (it says `$stmt->bindpParam`).

Comment: @carpenumidium Ok, good. But, then you should not update the `id` field. Just use `id` in the `WHERE` clause. Therefore, it should be the last `$stmt->bindParam()`.

Comment: I would update the fields in the order they appear in the table, too (even if only some fields are being update).

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Thanks, I really need to integrate better code organization into my workflow. Do I just need to move `id` to the end to stop it from updating?

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge you only need to bind in order if you are using `?` characters as parameter placeholders.  If you are using `:paramaterName` placeholders then it becomes a key:value pairing

Comment: @e_i_pi I beg to differ on a technicality. :-) While it may be possible to bind out of order with `:var` labels, I believe it is poor form to do so. Keeping them in order is the smartest way to fly.

Comment: I'm used to using libraries where I bind using an array of key / types object pairs. Never had a problem. If it makes you feel safer doing them in order, go for it, but it's just homeopathic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update

You seem to be doing the following in `view-account.php`:

```
try {
    $auth_user->update($id,$uname,$umob,$uaddr,$uacc,$upass);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Yet you're already `try/catch`'ing within your `update()` method. I assume it never gets to this as an error in your `if/elseif/elseif/else/etc` checks is picked up. Could you modify it to look like this for testing purposes:

```
$errors = [];
if ($uname == "") {
    $errors[] = "Please Enter Your Full Name!";
}
if ($umob == "") {
    $errors[] = "Please Enter Your Mobile No.!";
}
if ($uaddr == "") {
    $errors[] = 'Please Enter Your Address!';
}
if ($upass == "") {
    $errors[] = "Please Enter a Password!";
}
if (strlen($upass) < 6) {
    $errors[] = "Password must be atleast 6 characters";
}
// check errors
if (!empty($errors)) {
    print_r($errors);
    return false;
}
// otherwise try the query:
$obj = $auth_user->update($id, $uname, $umob, $uaddr, $uacc, $upass);
```

and let us know what comes up!

---

I assume you'd have an error thrown, something along the lines of;

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

This is because you're trying to bind on `:id` twice. You have to remember that a users `ID` is unique and should never change (*right?*).

Modify your query to look like this:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
    "UPDATE users
     SET
         name = :uname, 
         mobile = :umob,
         address = :uaddr,
         accNo = :uacc, 
         password = :upass
      WHERE id = :id"
);
```

---

#### Notes

- You're best to modify your "password change" functionality to have the user confirm their password (*`if(PASSWORD == PASSWORD_REPEAT) { .... SET PASSWORD...`*)
- Don't pass the user `ID` inside the form. It's insecure. Since it's in `$_SESSION` already, simply access it like that within your *`view-account.php`* file!

  - Why the above you ask? Simple. If I inspect your `<form...` element, I could easily modify that hidden input to be some other users `ID`, allowing me to change their passwords/information/etc.
  - And since it looks like you're dealing with "Bank" related information, I'd suggest doing this asap! Imagine If I could change "Barack Obama's" bank password and access his account.
- **Your form also doesn't have any `action` attribute...so it does nothing.. Best change that to your `view-account.php` page**
- I suggest removing your use of `strip_tags()`. It could ruin some fields (*i.e. passwords*). You're also already binding/preparing your statements (*Props to you on that, good work!*)
- While we're at it, you might want to look at your `view-account.php` file, It could be modified to stop the use of all those `if / elseif / elseif / else` statements. You're essentially checking all your fields and if it fails, you're adding an error message to an array, but if it passes you're running the query, this is bad practice. You should look at doing something similar to (*pseudo code*):

---

```
$errors = [];
if (!check_fields()) {
    $errors[] = THE FIELD ERROR MESSAGE;
}

// now check if your errors are empty or not
if(!empty($errors)) {
    // this means we have errors in the form.
    // return the errors array to the front end and handle it appropriately.
    return $errors;
}

// otherwise we can try the query here now!
try {
    // YOUR SQL UPDATE QUERY
} .....`
```

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, that's the (not so) funny part. And yep. Guilty about the careless form build. I put the id in a hidden field to have something to match the logged in user with. Bad practices all around from my part, I'm kinda (totally) flailing in the dark at the moment. Thanks for the heads-up though.

Comment: @carpenumidium What is `$auth_user`? I don't see you instantiating it anywhere? Ps, don't stress man, we all have to start somewhere and learn from our mistakes! Just keep going :). Lets sort this out!

Comment: I've updated the post with the whole php for view-account.php. `$auth_user` is user to instantiate the USER class from `class.user.php`. Thanks mate :)

Comment: I'm following this tutorial http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/php-login-and-registration-script-with.html and its forms didn't have an `action` attribute for forms. I'll try out your suggestions.

Comment: @carpenumidium That'd be because they form submit goes to the page it's on (*where the processing is done*), but because this is 2 separate files, you need to specify where the action needs to take place :-)

Comment: I feel like I may have been misleading with how crappily I've written my post, too tired. The form is in view_account.php itself. I will update OP with more deets.

edit: I tried out your code and it's still not posting btw. Thanks for the notes, will def come handy!

Comment: @carpenumidium So all of your code is in one file? Including the form?

Comment: The code for updating the form is in one file (extending the USER class from class.user.php), I've updated my post with the whole code for view_account.php.

Comment: Hi Darren, I think I didn't properly implement your changes as I didn't see any errors when I echoed it on the page. I got a Undefined Variable Notice. Anyway, Anthony in the comments pointed out my bindings were not in proper order which seems to post the update to the database!

Comment: @carpenumidium Well there you go mate! I've never had any issue with the orders before, but nice!

Comment: So, it was your answer which worked for me all along. I'd added everyone's code suggestions at the same time and kinda lost track of where and when, so I misattributed Anthony's solution as...the solution. Cheers!

Now I need to figure out how to update the `$_SESSION` variables because I can't see changes unless I log out and then back in.

Answer (score 4):

Righto, you have a few problems with things not matching up etc., which is to be expected if you are starting out.

Let's start with the HTML form.  There are two issues here:

1. The form has no action property, so it doesn't get submitted anywhere
2. The submit button is given a specific name and no value.  (While some will consider this okay, maybe we can try a different approach which is a little more sensible)

I would suggest your HTML form be changed to this:

```
<form method="post" action="view-account.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">
    <label for="full-name" class="input-info">
        <div class="label">full name</div>
        <input type="text" id="full-name" name="full-name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>">
    </label>
    <label for="mobile" class="input-info">
        <div class="label">mobile number</div>
        <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['mob']; ?>">
    </label>
    <label for="addr" class="input-info">
        <div class="label">address</div>
        <input id="addr" name="addr" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['addr']; ?>">
    </label>
    <label for="bank-acc" class="input-info">
        <div class="label">bank account number</div>
        <input type="text" id="bank-acc" name="bank-acc" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['accNo']; ?>">
    </label>
    <hr>
    <label for="password" class="input-info">
        <div class="label">password</div>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    </label>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
        Save Changes
    </button>
</form>
```

Now, once this form is submitted to view-account.php, we want to make sure that the submit button is "save" mode, so we change the first line of view-account.php to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] === 'save') {
```

This approach means we can have different submit buttons on the same form - we may in future want actions for save, delete, archive, etc.

Lastly, I notice that the `id` field in your database table is declared `AUTOINCREMENT`.  Great, exactly what you want, database `id` fields are internal unique identifiers that we let the database determine (in 99% of cases - there are edge cases where we like to define our own UIDs).  This means that there is a problem with your `UPDATE` statement.  You cannot update an auto-incremented field.  In your class.user.php file, change the declaration of `$stmt` to this:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
    "UPDATE users
    SET
        name = :uname, 
        mobile = :umob,
        address = :uaddr,
        accNo = :uacc, 
        password = :upass
    WHERE id = :id"
);
```

This should fix your code issues, I think I got everything.  *BUT*, there may be other problems.  If your code still does not work, I would suggest checking your error logs.  If you're not sure where they are, either check your `php.ini` file to see what the error log location is, or override the default location by putting this at the top of the page you're trying to debug:

```
ini_set("error_log", "/path/to/error.log");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the post! I tried out your amendments and in the error logs it's saying `[24-Feb-2017 01:57:42 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\gas\view_account.php on line 81` which is where the html form begins.

Comment: do <?php  print_r($_SESSION); ?> just before the form in the html section and see if $_SESSION['id'] is defined

Comment: What @DCR said, the array key `id` doesn't exist in the `$_SESSION` global variable.  Perhaps in session.php the session isn't starting, maybe there was never that key in the variable in the first place.  This is where the art of debugging is practiced :)